# List of tuples in Python sort by one of the values

Tags: python, list, sorting, duplicates, tuples

I have a long list of tuples like this:

```
[(169, 8), (170, 1), (170, 4), (170, 8), (171, 8), (172, 8), (173, 8), (174, 8), (175, 6), (175, 8), (176, 6), (176, 8), (177, 6), (177, 8), (178, 6), (178, 8), (179, 6), (179, 8), (180, 1), (180, 6), (180, 8), (181, 6), (181, 8), (183, 1), (183, 4), (183, 6), (183, 8), (184, 6)..]
```

all I need is to get rid of repetitions of the first value by choosing the highest second value, like this:

```
[(169, 8), (170, 8), (171, 8), (172, 8), (173, 8), (174, 8), (175, 8), (176, 8),  (177, 8), (178, 8), (179, 8), (180, 8), (181, 8), (183, 1), (183, 8), (184, 6)..]
```

8 is not always the highest value in the list.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
l = [(169, 8), (170, 1), (170, 4), (170, 8), (171, 8), (172, 8)]
print dict(sorted(l)).items()
```

Result:

```
[(169, 8), (170, 8), (171, 8), (172, 8)]
```

The idea is first to sort the list and then create a dictionary based on the sorted tuples. The key to the dictionary will be the first item. Because of the sorted order the highest second value will replace any other value for the same key. Then with `items` we transform the resulting dictionary to tuples again.